# twilio add parameter to StatusCallback from runtime

Tags: parameters, twilio, runtime

As,we  can  set  staus call  back  url  in number from console.is  there any  way  to  add  Parameters from  the  runtime  function to  this url?
Didn't find  related info  in documentation

Comment: What are you trying to achieve rather than how you are trying to achieve it leads to a much better answer.

Comment: i need to know a specific value of a variable from my runtime function when call is finished. this value will change on users activity,it is available only in runtime. From runtime we can send recording status and can send parameters with it.but,adding another unnecessary record is not helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to store state somewhere. You can use Twilio Sync, there are code examples below.

[Use Twilio Sync to create, read, update, delete persistent data](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/quickstart/serverless-functions-use-twilio-sync-to-create-read-update-delete-persistent-data)

[Sync Limits](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sync/limits)

Comment: I was trying to post data in realtime with axios from twilio serverless runtime function,it seems I could only achieve either post data by axios or send twiml response by voiceResponse.How can we do both one after another?         https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/quickstart/serverless-functions-make-a-write-request-to-an-external-api-json

Comment: this is the newer post in regard of above comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65548123/get-reltime-json-data-from-twilio-runtime-with-axios