# get real-time json data from twilio runtime with axios

Tags: json, axios, twilio, runtime

I am trying to achieve real-time data from  twilio server-less  function. I am using a boilerplate function edited a little bit.What I want is json data in server  and voice response in call consecutively .but the following code is not sending json data to server.

```
const axios = require('axios');

exports.handler = function (context, event, callback) {
let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
twiml.say('you are welcome ');


 const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://fafc4eac4162.ngrok.io/',
  timeout: 3000,

  });

 instance
   .post('/test', {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Twilio'
  })
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
 
  })
   .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
    return callback(error);
   });

  return callback(null, twiml);

  };
```

It shows below error,but it sends data successfully if I do not use the voice response callback  return callback(null, twiml) and rather use simple return callback(null, response.data);

```
  {"message":"timeout of 3000ms exceeded","name":"Error","stack":"Error: timeout of 3000ms 
 exceeded\n    at createError (/var/task/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)\n    
 at RedirectableRequest.handleRequestTimeout 
 (/var/task/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:280:16)\n    at Object.onceWrapper 
 (events.js:286:20)\n    at RedirectableRequest.emit (events.js:198:13)\n    at 
  Timeout._onTimeout (/var/task/node_modules/follow-redirects/index.js:166:13)\n    at 
  ontimeout (timers.j...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `return callback(null, twiml);` should be in the `.then` block.

```
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
    return callback(null, twiml);
  })
```

Also, the error indicates the 3000ms timeout is hit, is your application returning a 200-OK?

Comment: It will be very helpful ,if you have bit of  time to enlighten me ,why is it working putting the return callback inside .then() block?

Comment: Here is the explanation - https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/functions/invocation#callback-function

Comment: if i nest an axios instance inside another one, where should i put the rerurn callback statement? inside nested axios or parent axios instance?

Comment: Nest instances, when all the async operations are completed. If they can be done in parallel, then you can use a promise.all.